# Randbetween return only odd numbers

Tags: excel

I need to create a list of random numbers between two bounds in Excel.  The trick is the numbers need to be odd.  So I can't just use `randbetween()`.  Should I just use something like `=if(a1 % 2 =0) then a1=a1+1`.  I don't know the syntax for that in Excel but what I'm getting at is if the number is even (mod 2 =0) then add one.

Comment: Excel doesn't have syntax for that. The excel way is repeating the expression (`if(<formula> = <something>, <that same formula> + 1, <something else>)`), which works for deterministic expressions, but will obviously return a different random number when called the second time.

Comment: Gotcha.  I think I know what I'm going to do, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a little trick. [`CEILING`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ceiling-HP005209007.aspx) and [`FLOOR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/floor-HP005209094.aspx) have a second parameter which is what you need.

```
=CEILING(RANDBETWEEN(...),2)-1
```

Comment: You also need to make sure randbetween upper value is the next even value to remove bias. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could get a random number *n* with a different range, and calculate 2**n*+1 for your cell value. I presume lower bound is 0 (or 1), so your new range starts off at 0 as well (if not, see how you calculate the upper bound). For the upper bound, if you want *m* as your largest odd integer, then your upper bound is (obviously) `(m-1)/2`.

As an example, say you want odd numbers between 15 and 27. Your lower bound for randbetween will be `(15-1)/2 = 7`, and upper bound will be `(27-1)/2 = 13`. So, the cell formula will be `=2*randbetween(7, 13)+1`.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I'll clarify a bit, and add an example.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Any number multiplied with two will be even, so adding or subtracting that number by one will give you an odd number.  But you would have to change the randbetween() ranges for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use RAND() here to be compatible with earlier excel versions, generically this formula will give you an even distribution, assuming C2 contains the lower bound and D2 the upper (both odd numbers)

`=INT(RAND()*((D$2-C$2)/2+1))*2+C$2`

Answer (score 0):

I know I am in the game late, but wouldn't this be just as simple.

```
A1 = randbetween(0,100)
B1 = if(mod(A1,2)=0,A1+1,A1)
```

Comment: I don't think you want to repeat randbetween like that.

Comment: yeah, just did more testing and fixed answer. Thanks

Comment: You also have to be careful how you define the range as per vhallac's comment in GSerg's answer. If you use RANDBETWEEN(0,100) then B1 will give you odd numbers between 1 and 101.....but typically 101 will appear half as often as all the others (because only 1 number in A1, 100, will lead to B1 being 101 whereas all other odd numbers have two possible progenitors)....hence you need to use RANDBETWEEN(0,101) or similar

Comment: ah, gotcha, so by having the probability of getting 101 at 1/100 versus every other number being 2/100, it loses it's randomness factor a little. thanks.