# Excel function for multiple formula

Tags: excel

How can I do this equation in excel

```
If text "t" then goto cell x if not goto cell y
```

And perform function
I.e

```
If cell has letter t do (28.5%*cell) if not do (15%*cell)
```

Comment: You'll have to [repeat the expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606227/randbetween-return-only-odd-numbers#comment13741207_10606227), there's no way to "remember" something within a formula.

Answer (score 1):

> If text "t" then goto cell x if not goto cell y

Assuming you meant "resolve to" by goto, this could be what you are looking for:

```
=IF(S1="t",X1,Y1)
```

When the value of cell S1 is "t", the value of the cell the formula is in, would be the value of cell X1, Y1 otherwise.

> If cell has letter t do (28.5%*cell) if not do (15%*cell)

This would be the formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("*t*",A1)), 28.5% * B1, 15% * C1)
```

Some test-data:

```
   A      | B    | C  
1  mytest | 100  | 200
```

**EDIT**   a ','  was missed there.. I popped that into Excel and it didn't work.

should be  `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("*t*",A1),), 28.5% * B1, 15% * C1)`

and that works

Comment: yeah, sorry & thanks for the edit -  is there some automatic translator for german formulas anywhere?!

Answer (score 1):

So the way i understand, You have 3 columns, 1 with a letter, and 2 with numbers. column 1 is either t or something else, and then column 2 and 3 are various answers. So my solution assumes that the letter is column a, and the numbers are columns b and c, and the function goes in d. you can adjust accordingly if the columns are different. then you can drag the function down (or up if you place it in a cell thats on at the top) and it will adjust the row numbers.

`=IF(A1 = "t",B1 * 0.285,C1 * 0.15)`

so basically it takes cell A1 and checks if it is the letter t. if so, it takes the number in b1` and multiplies it by 28.5% and if not, it takes the number in c1 and multiplies it by 15%.