# RANDBETWEEN Every other row

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I need to RANDBETWEEN and display cell information with named entries that are on every other row. How can I do this? This is working `=INDEX($A$1:$A$23,RANDBETWEEN(0,ROWS($A$1:$A$23)),0)` but I need every other row please.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "display cell information with named entries". `MOD(ROW(),2)` will return a 0 on even rows and a 1 on odd rows, you could use this within an `IF` statement.  Also `ROWS($A$1:$A$23)` will always return 23 so you may as well use `RANDBETWEEN(0,23)`.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606227/randbetween-return-only-odd-numbers) answer to return random odd numbers.  You could then use `=INDEX($A$1:$A$23,CEILING(RANDBETWEEN(1,23),2)-1,0)`.

Comment: Could you update your question (edit button is under the excel-formula tag) and include an example of what you mean - maybe a screenshot or add a formatted table in the question - can format tables [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#).  I'm not understanding what _"one box to randomize the content of every other cell and display it and refresh it with F9"_ looks like.

Comment: Thank you for your example! I got it working flawlessly. I have it working for every other evens 9000 lines.